# How to send an google agenda invite via code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-app-invites

i am trying to send an invitation e-mail via a calendar app that i've been doing in php, is it possible to do it by code in any means?
Any framework would work for me, i'm using javascript and ajax, i've thought of doing it by python automatization with pyauotgui, but i've been wondering if there is not a code solution for that, thanks in advance for you all

my code as follow:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('meumodal')
    var fechar = document.getElementById('fecharmodal')
    
    
    
    //abrir o modal
    document.addEventListener.onclick = function OpenModal(){ 
        modal.style.display = 'block'
    }

})


function showModal(valorhora){
    var element = document.getElementById('modal');
    element.classList.add("show-modal")
    var hora = valorhora;
    let horariodecomeco = document.querySelector(".horario-inicio")
    horariodecomeco.value = hora;
    horariodecomeco.innerHTML = hora;
}



function registraDados(BtAgendar){
    var NomeSolicitante = document.getElementById('NomeSolicitante')
        NomeSolicitante = NomeSolicitante.value
        alert(NomeSolicitante)

    var EmailSolicitante = document.getElementById('EmailSolicitante')
        EmailSolicitante = EmailSolicitante.value
        alert(EmailSolicitante)

}




function hideModal(){
    var element = document.getElementById('modal')
    element.classList.remove('show-modal')
}



/*reconhecer valor do botão e mudar cor*/
function clickMouse(hora) {
    let horariodecomeco = document.querySelector("#horario-inicio")
    horariodecomeco += hora;

    switch(hora){
        case "07:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "07:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora1').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora1').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora1').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "08:00":          
            document.getElementById('btnHora2').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora2').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora2').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "08:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora3').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora3').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora3').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "09:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora4').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora4').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora4').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "09:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora5').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora5').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora5').disabled = true;    
            break;
        case "10:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora6').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora6').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora6').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "10:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora7').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora7').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora7').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "11:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora8').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora8').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora8').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "11:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora9').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora9').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora9').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "12:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora10').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora10').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora10').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "12:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora11').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora11').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora11').disabled = true;
            break;
        case "13:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora12').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora12').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora12').disabled = true; 
            break;  
        case "13:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora13').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora13').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora13').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "14:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora14').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora14').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora14').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "14:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora15').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora15').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora15').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "15:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora16').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora16').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora16').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "15:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora17').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora17').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora17').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "16:00":
            document.getElementById('btnHora18').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora18').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora18').disabled = true; 
            break;
        case "16:30":
            document.getElementById('btnHora19').style.background = "red";
            document.getElementById('btnHora19').innerHTML = 'Agendado';
            document.getElementById('btnHora19').disabled = true; 
            break;
    }
    
}

function clearParticipante(){
    let NovoParticipante = document.querySelector(".CamposConvidados");
    let CampoParticipante = '<div class="Linha-Convidado"><div class="Titulo">Nome convidado</div><div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="text" class="convidado"></div><div class="Titulo">E-mail convidado</div><div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="text" class="emailconvidado"</div></div>'
    NovoParticipante.innerHTML = CampoParticipante;
}

function AdicionandoParticipante() {
    let NovoParticipante = document.querySelector(".CamposConvidados");
    let CampoParticipante = '<div class="Linha-Convidado"><div class="Titulo">Nome convidado</div><div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="text" name ="nome_convidado" class="convidado"></div><div class="Titulo">E-mail convidado</div><div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="text" name="email_convidado"  class="emailconvidado"</div></div>'
    NovoParticipante.innerHTML += CampoParticipante;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/Agenda.css">
    <title>Reserva de Sala de Reunião</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <section class="info">
            <header>
                <h1>Rua alberto de nobrega</h1>
                <span>Sala <?php echo $numerosala ?></span>
            </header>
            <main>
                <div class="agenda">
                    <span>Agendamentos do dia:</span>
                    <div class="lista" >
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora"   onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="07:00">Horario: 07:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora1"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="07:30">Horario: 07:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora2"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="08:00">Horario: 08:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora3"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="08:30">Horario: 08:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora4"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="09:00">Horario: 09:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora5"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="09:30">Horario: 09:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora6"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="10:00">Horario: 10:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora7"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="10:30">Horario: 10:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora8"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="11:00">Horario: 11:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora9"  onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="11:30">Horario: 11:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora10" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="12:00">Horario: 12:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora11" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="12:30">Horario: 12:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora12" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="13:00">Horario: 13:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora13" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="13:30">Horario: 13:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora14" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="14:00">Horario: 14:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora15" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="14:30">Horario: 14:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora16" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="15:00">Horario: 15:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora17" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="15:30">Horario: 15:30</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora18" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="16:00">Horario: 16:00</button>
                        <button class="botao" id="btnHora19" onClick="showModal(this.value), clearParticipante()" value="16:30">Horario: 16:30</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </section>
        <section>
            <iframe id="frame" src="Calendario.php?numerosala=<?php echo $numerosala ?>&dia=<?php echo $dia ?>+ &mes=<?php echo $mes ?>&ano=<?php echo $ano ?>" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border: none;"></iframe>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<footer>
    
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/Agenda.js"></script> 
    <div class="modal" id='modal'>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span  class="closeModal" onclick= hideModal()  >&times;</span>
            <br>
            <form id="formulario_agenda" action="https://ssl9348.websiteseguro.com/ricardoalmeida/ti_desenvolvimento/Projeto-Sala-de-Reuniao/App/Model/insert.php" method="POST">
                <div class="Formulario">        
                    <div class="CamposSolicitante">
                        <div class="Titulo">Nome solicitante</div>            
                        <div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="text" name="nome_solicitante" id="solicitante" class="CaixaDeTexto" required="true"></div>
                        <div class="Titulo">E-mail solicitante</div>
                        <div class="Caixa-Texto"><input type="email" name="email_solicitante" id="emailsolicitante" class="CaixaDeTexto" required="true"></div>

                    
            
                    <div class="CamposConvidados">
                      
                    </div>
                    <span>Horário de Inicio da Reunião:</span><span class="horario-inicio"></span> <br>
                    <span id="horario-final">Previsão de Término da Reunião </span><input class="horario-final" type="time" name="hora_final" required>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" class="horario-inicio" name="hora_comeco" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" id="numerosala" name="sala" value="<?php echo $numerosala ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="dia" id="diaagenda" value="<?php echo $dia ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="mes" id="mesagenda" value="<?php echo $mes ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ano" id="anoagenda"value="<?php echo $ano ?>">
                    <div class="Controle-Formulario">
                            <button type="button" class="BtAdcParticipante" onclick="AdicionandoParticipante()">Adicionar Participante</button>
                            <button type="submit" form="formulario_agenda" class="BtAgendar" value="Enviar" name="enviar" onclick="clickMouse(hora), hideModal()"> Agendar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>        
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: There is [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in PHP available, but you can also use more advanced [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class to send e-mails. You can also attach [.ics/.ical](https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/) file to your e-mails with a reminder - it's a text file you can generate yourself with plain PHP, use existing file as an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @cezaryta i was looking for an alternate way of sending invites, the program is already sending e-mail via PHP Mailer, but seems i will have to use ICS file to be able to send an nicely invite, again, thanks for the answer and if u mind to put this as an answer so i can thumbs it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [mail](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function in PHP available, but you can also use more advanced [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class to send e-mails. You can also attach [.ics/.ical](https://icalendar.org/RFC-Specifications/iCalendar-RFC-5545/) file to your e-mails with a reminder - it's a text file you can generate yourself with plain PHP, use existing file as an example.

The mentioned iCalendar website has an [iCalendar format validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) you can use to test your own generated files.

Three important things you need to pay attention to when generating calendar files - timezone definition, line width limit (75 octets) and line breaks that SHOULD BE `CRLF` (or `\r\n`) even if you generate them in Unix/Linux. [More information](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-1-content-lines.html).